# Postgresql assign mutliple row query result to variable and continue execution

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a script that calls several stored procedures in PostgreSQL and print the result of some of them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION script(
vtoken character varying) 
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  aux character varying;
BEGIN

PERFORM (SELECT acquire_table(vtoken));

-- This query gets the dynamically generated token for the client in that codebar
aux := (SELECT token 
                FROM clients c JOIN tables t ON c.tablekey = t.tablekey 
                WHERE codebar = vtoken);

PERFORM (SELECT order_drinks(aux, '{1}', '{1}'));

--EXECUTE (SELECT issue_ticket(aux));

PERFORM (SELECT order_drinks(aux, '{1}', '{1}'));


END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

The issue_ticket() function returns a multiple row result, I'd like to print it directly and continue execution of next function (order_drinks()). If I do PERFORM it does not show the results, and if I just try to execute the SELECT query as it is, it asks to assign return value to variable.

Answer (score 5):

The usual approach is to return a rowset using `returns table`.  The client calling the function can then print it.  The function itself continues to run after the `return`.  For example:

```
create or replace function script() 
RETURNS TABLE (col1 int)
language plpgsql
as $_$ begin
RETURN QUERY (VALUES (6), (7), (6*7));
RAISE NOTICE 'continuing after return';
end;
$_$;
select * from script();
```

This prints:

```
NOTICE:  continuing after return
 col1 
------
    6
    7
   42
(3 rows)
```

You can also store the result of the function in a (temporary) table:

```
create or replace function script2() 
returns table (col1 int)
language plpgsql
as $_$ 
begin
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (id int) ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT * FROM script();
return query (select * from temp_table);
end;
$_$;
select * from script2();
```

This prints:

```
NOTICE:  continuing after return
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into temp_table select * from script() s where s.col1 < 42"
PL/pgSQL function script2() line 4 at SQL statement
 col1 
------
    6
    7
(2 rows)
```

Comment: So it continues execution even after the return?, ok thank you!

Comment: Yeah, functions continue after `return`.  You can even use multiple returns, as long as they have the same recordset defintion